# How do I find the equation of this curve?

Tags: graphing-functions, curves, parametrization

Say we have the curve $$\vec r(t)=(at-a\sin t,a+a\cos t)$$ for $a$ a positive constant, how do we find it's explicit equation? I've tried plotting it on desmos and I got this (choosing $a=1$):

[image: Plotting of the curve]

Which if you find the points on the extremes and on the minima and got $(0,2a),(\pi a,0),(2\pi a,2a)$ which has all the characteristics of a periodic equation but I don't know how to find it, is it even possible?

(Note: by equation I mean the form $f(x,y)=0$)

Comment: Solve $y=a+a\cos(t)$ for $t$ and plug it in for $x(t)$ to get a form $x=f(y)$

Comment: Is there a typo? Your graph looks like a [cycloid](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cycloid), but your $x$-coordinate has a term $t \sin t$, which doesn't parametrize such a curve.

Comment: @SammyBlack yes, it was a typo, just edited, thanks

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid#Equations

Comment: This question has been asked a few times before on this site.